# How to read all content from HttpEntity and BufferedHttpEntity in java

Tags: java, http, buffer

I wrote a HttpClient used for sending a txt file in java. All is well, but at the server side, I only received a small portion of a file. I've googled around and it turns out that java HttpClient has a 8KB buffer, so a workaround to this problem is to use BufferedHttpEntity. But I still can't figure out how to propertly use it. Can somebody help me? Here's my server side code:

```
public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
        HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
    String responseBack = "";

    HttpEntity entity = null;

    // Check if the request has an entity
    if (request instanceof HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) {
        // If it is, get the entity from it
        entity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();
    }

    BufferedHttpEntity buffEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

    InputStream is = buffEntity.getContent();
    String s = getStringFromInputStream(is);

    // Log the data received
    Log.i("Data Received", s);

    // Make a simple response back using the data received
    responseBack = "Successfully received!";

    // Create a new entity for the response and then set it
    HttpEntity entityResponse = new StringEntity(responseBack, HTTP.UTF_8);
    response.setEntity(entityResponse);
}
```